# Python Check if the Spatial Reference is the same for both feature classes

Tags: python, arcpy

```
... for 'PA_County' in feature_classes:
...     spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe("PA_County",{C:/coordsystems/NAD 1983.prj}).SpatialReference
...     if spatial_ref.name == "Unknown" :
...         print ("PA_County has unknown spatial reference".format("PA_County"))
...     else:
...         print ("PA_County:Springs".format(PA_Springs, spatial_ref.name))
...         
Parsing error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (line 2)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

This code is not doing what you think it is doing.  Your code is trying to find the spatial reference of a string.  I think what you are trying to do is this:

    `for entry in feature_classes:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(entry)
        if desc.spatialReference.name == "Unknown" :
            print "%s has unknown spatial reference" %desc.baseName
        else:
            print "%s has spatial reference %s" %(desc.baseName, desc.spatialReference.name)`